# TSQL - Query to get count of items associated to each category and subcategory

Tags: sql, t-sql, hierarchical-data, categories

I have the following tables:

```
Categories
=================================
CategoryID |   ParentID   | Text 
---------------------------------
     1           NULL       Text
     2            1         Text
     3           NULL       Text
     4            1         Text

Items
=================================
  ItemID  |  CategoryID  | Text
---------------------------------
     1           1         Text
     2           2         Text
     3           4         Text
     4           3         Text
```

Bear in mind this is not an n-level hierarchy, the categories have only 2 levels, so no category can have a parentID of 2 for instance.

What I am looking for is a way to return the categories with an extra column which displays the number of items that the category owns (including its subcategories).

i.e. I'm looking for a single query (or procedure) which can return something like the following:

```
      Categories
============================================
CategoryID |   ParentID   | Text  |  Count
--------------------------------------------
     1           NULL       Text      3
     2            1         Text      1
     3           NULL       Text      1
     4            1         Text      1
```

My current method of getting the items associated to a category is as follows (Given a categoryID, @CategoryID):

```
SELECT * FROM Items
WHERE CategoryID 
IN (SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories where ParentID = @CategoryID or CategoryID = @CategoryID)
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to link this to a select query for the categories themselves.
It's probably very simple, but I have tried methods using CTE's, various group by clauses, but the hierarchical nature of the categories seems to throw my logic off.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The query also needs to account for categories with no items associated to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to join items to categories, and group by on any fields you need from the category table:

```
SELECT  c.CategoryID
,       c.ParentID
,       c.Text
,       count(distinct i.ItemID)
FROM    Categories c
LEFT JOIN
        Categories c2
ON      c.CategoryID = c2.ParentID
LEFT JOIN    
        Items i
ON      i.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
        or i.CategoryID = c2.CategoryID
GROUP BY
        c.CategoryID
,       c.ParentID
,       c.Text
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! - firstly, how do I account for the use of the variables? (I'd instead used c.CategoryID) - then this query seems to produce a count for only a single category node (it doesnt account for children) i.e. in this example, the count produce for category 1 would be 1.
Also, the join doesnt seem to account for categories without any items associated to them? I'll update my question :)

Comment: @Jaime: That clarifies your question :)  I've removed the variables.  You can include categories without any items with `left join`.

Comment: Thanks! :) Although now it seems there is a strange effect - it arbitrarily assigns the count on all of the categories as 1, so for instance, a category with 1 item asociated (no subs) would have a count of 1, but a category with 0 items also has a count of 1? Maybe on a similar note - the count of category 1 seems to display as 4 instead of 3, i'll try and figure it out, but then it wont display as the answer for other people, so this comment should clarify things :)

Comment: @Jaime: Did you use the version with `count(*)`? That would return `1` for a category that doesn't match any rows.  `count(distinct i.ItemID)` should fare better.

Comment: That sorted it out perfectly :) Thanks again!

Comment: how does the keyword "distinct" help here ? I had written exactly the same query in a notepad except for the distinct keyword

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: The first left join causes an item that belongs to the parent to be repeated for each child.  The `distinct` prevents those items from being counted twice.